# How to hack a Win95 machine?

Tags: windows, known-vulnerabilities, operating-systems

While playing with old operating systems, I came across that there are no remote code execution exploits available for Win95 machines, running just file share (no IIS or anything else). Win95 neither has port 445, nor named pipes.

My scenario is that a file share for the whole OS disk is world writeable (empty password is set), and just by uploading/renaming/modifying files through the file share, I want to achieve instant code execution, without the need to restart the OS. So for example adding new entries to autoexec.bat is not a valid solution. I read tricks about replacing windows\rundll32.exe with a custom executable, but it did not work.

Could you please help me out, if there is any way to get instant RCE with these constraints?

Comment: This reminds me of the good old: `\\hostname\c$\con\con` In case you're looking for a way to remotely crash a Win95 machine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been posted at the following blog page:
http://jumpespjump.blogspot.hu/2014/05/hacking-windows-95-part-2.html

Alltogether, two prerequisites were needed, an SMB share with write privileges for the whole disk, and Windows 95 Plus! for the scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. You *might* try and see whether it's possible to exploit [MS99-049](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms99-049) through a specially crafted SMB request, but it's a long shot, and anyway, the PC might be patched.

Other possibilities for hacking (not instant RCE) are creating an executable in the hope it will be launched on the remote system (something like `StripPoker_Install.exe`), or an executable containing a resource exploit against Explorer - again, someone has to open the upload folder on the remote site - or check whether *some* services are installed after all, e.g. DCOM.

As for the need to restart the OS, an unpatched Windows 95 [will do that anyway](http://news.cnet.com/2100-1040-222391.html) sooner or later.

Comment: Although your suggestions might work, but not in my case. In my case there is no user interaction, no user sitting in front of the desktop. And about the "Windows may crash after 49.7 days" part, it is just likely (not for sure) that it will crash, but if it crashes, it won't reboot.

Comment: Without user interaction or a service reading or executing those files, there is nothing to hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think telnet is loaded by default in win95/98. May be if you can exploit or bruteforce telnet with Metasploit or something similar you will gain access.

[Microsoft Windows 95/98 IE5/Telnet Heap Overflow Vulnerability](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/19462/)

Comment: That report isn't about a telnet service but the telnet client. (I don't think Win95 even _had_ services, let alone a telnet service enabled by default.)

Comment: Only ports regarding file sharing (135-139) are open by default. No telnet service is running.

Comment: I have found one small step to achieve my goal. It is the ms00-072 vulnerability, and the tool "Share Password Checker" from Securityfriday. I still need something for instant RCE through the share.